# How can I access global data from another class in Flutter?

Tags: class, flutter, global-variables

I have a simple class like;

```
import 'dart:io';
class IDCardClass {
  File frontImageFile;
  File backImageFile;
}
```

From `front_test.dart` class I need to assign a data to `frontImageFile` and `back_test.dart` class I need to assign a data to `backImageFile`.

In my `home.dart` or another `***.dart` class I need to get `frontImageFile` and `backImageFile` to show it to user.

My question is How can I access global data from another class in Flutter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make the variables to `static` like this:

```
class IDCardClass {
  static File frontImageFile;
  static File backImageFile;
}
```

Just import the class into the other class and access the variables.

```
import 'package:your_projectname/your_folder/IDCardClass.dart';

.....

var imageFile = IDCardClass.frontImageFile;

.....
```

Comment: Thanks, can I also assign new value using ststic?

Comment: Could you explain more about new values?

Comment: In home page user captures an image and assign to frontImageFile and later user can access the file from another class. And if user wants certain class user again assign new value to frontImageFile

Comment: static means that frontImageFile is the same reference wherever you get or set it. In memory there is only one copy and everyone is sharing that copy.

Comment: is there a way to do this with final variables? 
because I'm trying to call this and its showing me an error in snapshot.data

Comment: can accessing the static variable from different places cause concurrency issues?

Comment: @TiagoSantos I would suspect so, but the user didn't mention anything about concurrency. Also this implementation would break clean architecture. Think as of today Google is recommending the BLoC pattern. If you have a better solution please feel free to add it as an answers. I'll vote it up!  =)